# PHP Google Calendar get Event from specific calendar

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I have 2 or more calendars in Google Calendar.
I can add events to that specific calendar like:

```
[...]
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service);
$service = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);

//Set up  that loop again to find the new calendar:
$calFeed = $service->getCalendarListFeed();
foreach ($calFeed as $calendar) {
    if($calendar->title->text == "Calendar2")
         $appCalUrl = $calendar->content->src;
    }
}
[...]

try {

    $event           = $service->newEventEntry();
    $event->title    = $service->newTitle($title);

    $when            = $service->newWhen();
    $when->startTime = $start;
    $when->endTime   = $end;

    $event->when     = array($when);
    $newEvent        = $service->insertEvent($event, $appCalUrl);

    // fetch URI for edit, delete
    $uri = $newEvent->id->text;

} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getResponse();
}
```

$uri results in a string like:
http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/7b06drcai3lhc4lhhb0lgvv7sk%40group.calendar.google.com/private/full/ndp7g62tbbvknhi8bbhh9jfu9o

Then, using:

```
try {

     $title = "test2";
     $event = $service->getCalendarEventEntry($uri);
     $event->title = $service->newTitle($title);
    } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
    die("Error: " . $e->getResponse());
}
```

This always results in an error like: BAD / Invalid URI

I've been searching, and in multiple examples all says that the URI format should be something like:

```
getCalendarEventEntry('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full/' . $id);
```

Getting only the ID dont work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the awnser:

The format for the string is:

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/$calendar_id%40group.calendar.google.com/private/full/$event_id
```